# how to save textcolor on textview by using NSUserdefaults

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, nsuserdefaults, uicolor

I am the beginner of iphone developer,my problem is how to save the textcolor on textview.
i want to taken 3buttons in each one set one color.when i tap the button.what the button had color text write on textview and at the same time save the feature also.when i open the application it does not lose the old feature.so how can solve the problem please help me.

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can archive any object and store it in user defaults. To set it:

```
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"color1"];
```

And to retreive it:

```
NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"color1"];
UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
```